# TestNG: Unable to see 'Testng' in run configuration in eclipse kepler in ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, testng

I am unable to see 'testng' in run configuration. Does anyone have faced the same issue? 
I am having ubuntu 12.0.4 version. Moreover, i've also installed testng plug-in from its' official website. JDK version is 1.6.0_36 and eclipse kepler version 4.0 above. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you restart the eclipse?

Comment: Yes..tried too many times.Also tried latest and previous versions of testng too but no luck :-(